# Complex Numbers and exponential form and roots

Tags: complex-numbers

The roots of $z^7 = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$ are $\text{cis } \theta_1, \text{cis } \theta_2, \dots, \text{cis } \theta_7,$ where $ 0^\circ \le \theta_k < 360^\circ $for all $ 1 \le k \le 7$. Find $\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \dots + \theta_7$. Give your answer in degrees.

In exponential form this is $z^7 = e^ \left(5 \pi i/4 \right)$. How should I simplify? Thanks

Comment: What is $\text{cis}$? Do you by chance mean $\cos$?

Comment: @AlexR  cis is short for $cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)$

Comment: @AlexR: "cis" is a commonly used abbreviation for "cosine plus $i$ times the sine." In other words, $$\operatorname{cis}\theta=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=e^{i\theta}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, by DeMoivre's Theorem, we have $$(\operatorname{cis}\theta_k)^7=\operatorname{cis}(7\theta_k)$$ for $k=1,...,7.$ We need for $$(\operatorname{cis}\theta_k)^7=\operatorname{cis} 225^\circ,$$ as you've already determined, and so we need $$\operatorname{cis}(7\theta_k)=\operatorname{cis} 225^\circ\\\frac{\operatorname{cis}(7\theta_k)}{\operatorname{cis} 225^\circ}=1\\\operatorname{cis}(7\theta_k-225^\circ)=1$$ for $k=1,...,7.$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly...for $k=1$, we take $$\operatorname{cis}(7\theta_1)=\operatorname{cis} 225^\circ$$ and then somehow determine $\theta_1$, and repeat for $k=2,3,4,5,6,7$?

Comment: No, that's getting further from the answer. Rather, think about the solutions set for the equation $$\operatorname{cis}\theta=1.$ This will let you get rid of the $\operatorname{cis},$ and find all solutions to the original equation. Then you can find the seven solutions in the desired interval.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, what are the solutions to $$\operatorname{cis}\theta=1,$$ or, more usefully put, $$\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=1+0i$$

Comment: $\cos \theta = 1$ and $\sin \theta = 0$, so $\theta$ = 360 degrees/$2\pi$.

Comment: Well, close. Rather, $\theta=360n^\circ$ for some integer $n.$ We need only find the $7$ values of $n$ for which the solution of $$7\theta_k-225^\circ=360n^\circ$$ lies in the desired interval.

Comment: From there, the rest is immediate.

Answer (score 0):

The roots are $e^{2k\pi i/7}$ ($k=0,\ldots,6$). Write them as $r^k$ where $r = e^{2\pi i/7}$. So the sum is (using the simple formula for summing a finite geometric series)

$$\sum_{k=0}^6 r^k = \frac{1-r^7}{1-r} = \frac{1 - e^{2\pi i}}{1-e^{2\pi i/7}} = 0$$.

Comment: This is incorrect. The roots you have given are the roots of $z^7=1.$ Also, we are not summing up the roots, but rather the *arguments* of said roots lying in $[0^\circ,360^\circ).$

Answer (score 0):

$\def\cis{\operatorname{cis}}$Let's consider a more general problem. We have $a=r\cis\alpha$ and we write its $n$th roots as
\begin{gather}
\sqrt[n]{r}\cis\frac{\beta}{n}\\
\sqrt[n]{r}\cis\left(\frac{\beta}{n}+\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\\
\sqrt[n]{r}\cis\left(\frac{\beta}{n}+2\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\\
\dots\\
\sqrt[n]{r}\cis\left(\frac{\beta}{n}+(n-1)\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)
\end{gather}
Can you sum up all those angles? Use $360$ instead of $2\pi$ if you so prefer or are forced to.